# What triggers and what happens on onPageDataChanged?

Tags: android, callback

In a project I am  working on, there is a class that uses `Modelcallbacks`. One of its callbacks is `onPageDataChanged`.

I have searched on the net but cannot find what triggers and what happens on the `callback` function.

Can someone please explain it to me? Thanks in advance!

```
@Override
    public void onPageDataChanged(Page changedPage) {
        ArrayList<ReviewItem> reviewItems = new ArrayList<ReviewItem>();
        for (Page page : mWizardModel.getCurrentPageSequence()) {
            page.getReviewItems(reviewItems);
        }
        Collections.sort(reviewItems, new Comparator<ReviewItem>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(ReviewItem a, ReviewItem b) {
                return a.getWeight() > b.getWeight() ? +1 : a.getWeight() < b.getWeight() ? -1 : 0;
            }
        });
        mCurrentReviewItems = reviewItems;

        if (mReviewAdapter != null) {
            mReviewAdapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
        }
    }
```

Comment: please share your code

Comment: I have added it.